# How to programmatic disable C# Console Application's Quick Edit mode?

Tags: c#, console-application

I've tried several solutions found, like the one ->

http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/console-writeline-hangs-if-user-click-into-console-window-t1412701.html

But, I observed that mode in `GetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, out int mode)` will be different for different console app. It is not constant.

Can I disable mouse clicks (right/left buttons) on a console application to achieve the same scenario. I found that it can be done with `IMessageFilter` but only for Window Form Application and not for console application.

Comment: It's off by default from what I know, if the user wants to enable it then who are you to tell them differently?

Comment: Actually, the same scenario happened yesterday, when one of our console based C# application that act as a server goes LIVE. Some one from implementation team may has mistakenly turn on quick edit mode & than click on window too unintentionally. That freezes the UI thread. It took 2 hours of hustle before actually finding out that problem wasn't technical. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to disable quick edit mode, you need to call [GetConsoleMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683167%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the current mode. Then clear the bit that enables quick edit, and call [SetConsoleMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686033%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Assuming you have the managed prototypes for the unmanaged functions, you would write:

```
const int ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT = 0x0040;

IntPtr consoleHandle = GetConsoleWindow();
UInt32 consoleMode;

// get current console mode
if (!GetConsoleMode(consoleHandle, out consoleMode))
{
    // Error: Unable to get console mode.
    return;
}

// Clear the quick edit bit in the mode flags
mode &= ~ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT;

// set the new mode
if (!SetConsoleMode(consoleHandle, consoleMode))
{
    // ERROR: Unable to set console mode
}
```

If you want to disable mouse input, you want to clear the mouse input bit.

```
const int ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT = 0x0010;

mode &= ~ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT;
```

Comment: @M.Babcock: Yes, that's what the linked code *attempts* to do. But the linked code is getting the standard input handle rather than the console window handle (might be different). It also hard-codes a console mode, which could change many different settings. This code changes only the one setting.

Comment: @Jim Mischel - using IntPtr consoleHandle = GetConsoleWindow() leads to fall under if condition and than returned. So i used  public const  int STD_INPUT_HANDLE = -10; IntPtr handle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE); GetConsoleMode(handle, out consoleMode) to get the mode.  Is there any thing i am missing ?

Comment: It's a little bit ago, but some little additional hint:
[Source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130506-00/?p=4453/)

has important information: for Disableing QuickEdit Mode, the Extended Flag MUST be set on SetConsole.

If you call SetConsole without QUICK & without EXTENDED : the flag change, but quickedit is still enabled.

To Disable:
mode &= ~ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT;
mode |=   ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS;

Comment: @JimMischel I am not the one who down-voted this. But, I think there is a tiny typo in your code: the line `mode &= ~ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT;` I think should be `consoleMode &= ...`. You might want to correct that.

Answer (score 79):

For those like me that like *no-brainer* code to copy/paste, here is the code inspired from the accepted answer:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

static class DisableConsoleQuickEdit {

   const uint ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT = 0x0040;

   // STD_INPUT_HANDLE (DWORD): -10 is the standard input device.
   const int STD_INPUT_HANDLE = -10;

   [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
   static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);

   [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
   static extern bool GetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, out uint lpMode);

   [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
   static extern bool SetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, uint dwMode);

   internal static bool Go() {

      IntPtr consoleHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

      // get current console mode
      uint consoleMode;
      if (!GetConsoleMode(consoleHandle, out consoleMode)) {
         // ERROR: Unable to get console mode.
         return false;
      }

      // Clear the quick edit bit in the mode flags
      consoleMode &= ~ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT;

      // set the new mode
      if (!SetConsoleMode(consoleHandle, consoleMode)) {
         // ERROR: Unable to set console mode
         return false;
      }

      return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: Here's a Python equivalent if one needs it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76855923/15016163

Answer (score 11):

Having read above answers, GetConsoleWindow() can not be used. Instead GetStdHandle() must be used.

So here's a copy and paste class for enabling/disabling QuickEditMode. Call **ConsoleWindow.QuickEditMode(false);** to disable quick edit mode for the console window.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class ConsoleWindow
{
    private static class NativeFunctions
    {
        public enum StdHandle : int
        {
            STD_INPUT_HANDLE = -10,
            STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11,
            STD_ERROR_HANDLE = -12,
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle); //returns Handle

        public enum ConsoleMode : uint
        {
            ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT = 0x0004,
            ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS = 0x0080,
            ENABLE_INSERT_MODE = 0x0020,
            ENABLE_LINE_INPUT = 0x0002,
            ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT = 0x0010,
            ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT = 0x0001,
            ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE = 0x0040,
            ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT = 0x0008,
            ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT = 0x0200,

            //screen buffer handle
            ENABLE_PROCESSED_OUTPUT = 0x0001,
            ENABLE_WRAP_AT_EOL_OUTPUT = 0x0002,
            ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING = 0x0004,
            DISABLE_NEWLINE_AUTO_RETURN = 0x0008,
            ENABLE_LVB_GRID_WORLDWIDE = 0x0010
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool GetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, out uint lpMode);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool SetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, uint dwMode);
    }

    public static void QuickEditMode(bool Enable)
    {
        //QuickEdit lets the user select text in the console window with the mouse, to copy to the windows clipboard.
        //But selecting text stops the console process (e.g. unzipping). This may not be always wanted.
        IntPtr consoleHandle = NativeFunctions.GetStdHandle((int)NativeFunctions.StdHandle.STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
        UInt32 consoleMode;

        NativeFunctions.GetConsoleMode(consoleHandle, out consoleMode);
        if (Enable)
            consoleMode |= ((uint)NativeFunctions.ConsoleMode.ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE);
        else
            consoleMode &= ~((uint)NativeFunctions.ConsoleMode.ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE);

        consoleMode |= ((uint)NativeFunctions.ConsoleMode.ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS);

        NativeFunctions.SetConsoleMode(consoleHandle, consoleMode);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who use vb.net

```
Const ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT As UInteger = &H40
Const STD_INPUT_HANDLE As Integer = -10


   <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
Public Function GetStdHandle(ByVal nStdHandle As Integer) As IntPtr
End Function

<DllImport("kernel32.dll")>
Private Function GetConsoleMode(ByVal hConsoleHandle As IntPtr, <Out> ByRef lpMode As UInteger) As Boolean
End Function

<DllImport("kernel32.dll")>
Private Function SetConsoleMode(ByVal hConsoleHandle As IntPtr, ByVal dwMode As UInteger) As Boolean
End Function 

    Friend Function Go() As Boolean
    Dim consoleHandle As IntPtr = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE)
    Dim consoleMode As UInteger

    If Not GetConsoleMode(consoleHandle, consoleMode) Then
        Return False
    End If

    consoleMode = consoleMode And Not ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT

    If Not SetConsoleMode(consoleHandle, consoleMode) Then
        Return False
    End If

    Return True
End Function

sub main()
go()
end sub
```

Comment: But the question is about C#.

Comment: But this answer is for those who use vb.net

Answer (score 0):

By used combination of codes on below, I'm be able to enable or disable the Quick Edit mode.

```
const int ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT = 0x0040;

// STD_INPUT_HANDLE (DWORD): -10 is the standard input device.
const int STD_INPUT_HANDLE = -10;

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool GetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, out int lpMode);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool SetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, int dwMode);
```

To enable, simple do `currentConsoleMode &= ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT;`

And to disable, do 
`currentConsoleMode &= ~ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT`

And then call **SetConsoleMode**.

Answer (score -1):

I just happened to stumble over the same problem with quick edit mode enabled in my console application, which is written in C, and has been working under windows 7 32 bit for ages. After porting (well not really porting, but adapting some code lines) it to windows 10 64 Bit (still being a 32 bit application), I observed the same behaviour. 
So I searched for a solution.

But for a reason unknown to me, the code works the other way round, i.e setting the bit `ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE` in the mode parameter actually disables quick edit mode. And resetting the bit enables the quick edit mode...???

Here is my code:

```
    /// <summary>
/// This flag enables the user to use the mouse to select and edit text. To enable
/// this option, you must also set the ExtendedFlags flag.
/// </summary>
const int QuickEditMode = 64;

// ExtendedFlags must be combined with
// InsertMode and QuickEditMode when setting
/// <summary>
/// ExtendedFlags must be enabled in order to enable InsertMode or QuickEditMode.
/// </summary>
const int ExtendedFlags = 128;

BOOLEAN EnableQuickEdit()
{
    HWND conHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    int mode;
    DWORD dwLastError = GetLastError();
    if (!GetConsoleMode(conHandle, &mode))
    {
        // error getting the console mode. Exit.
        dwLastError = GetLastError();
        return (dwLastError == 0);
    }
    else 
        dwLastError = 0;
    mode = mode & ~QuickEditMode;

    if (!SetConsoleMode(conHandle, mode | ExtendedFlags))
    {
        // error setting console mode.
        dwLastError = GetLastError();
    }
    else
        dwLastError = 0;
    return (dwLastError == 0);
}

BOOLEAN DisableQuickEdit()
{
    HWND conHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    int mode;
    DWORD dwLastError = GetLastError();

    if (!GetConsoleMode(conHandle, &mode))
    {
        // error getting the console mode. Exit.
        dwLastError = GetLastError();
        return (dwLastError == 0);
    }
    else
        dwLastError = 0;

    mode = mode | QuickEditMode;

    if (!SetConsoleMode(conHandle, mode))
    {
        // error getting the console mode. Exit.
        dwLastError = GetLastError();
    }
    else
        dwLastError = 0;
    return (dwLastError == 0);
}
```

Greetings Wolfgang

Comment: The question is about C#