# My program stop if user click the console, how do I prevent it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, console

How do I prevent the program from stopping when the user press the console?

For example:
[image]

I'm trying to create a loop in python where it's printing out number from 0-1000, but when the user click the console, it stopped

How do I prevent this?

I can't find a site or any stackoverflow answer, what I get is only in `c#` language. I want a `python` language

Here is a similar problem in `c#` [Code stops executing when a user clicks on the console window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39250218/code-stops-executing-when-a-user-clicks-on-the-console-window)

The problem was not on the code, because the code is

```
for i in range(1000):
 print(i)
```

EDITED: I want to make the Quick-Edit disabled in python code?

Comment: Can you add code to reproduce your issue? I don't understand what your current problem is.

Comment: The code was fine, but when I press the console the program stopped

Comment: @Faran2007 You should add the code so we are able to see whats going on

Comment: @Shadesfear no, no, no. The problem was not on the code

Comment: Taken from the link the linked to: 
This happens if you have Quick Edit Mode enabled on the console window. If you right-click on the title bar and select Properties, then select the Options tab, you can check to see if Quick Edit Mode is enabled. If you disable Quick Edit Mode, then the scrolling doesn't stop when you click in the window.

Comment: @Shadesfear how do I disable it in my python code?

Comment: @Faran2007 are you on windows ?

Comment: @Shadesfear yes

Comment: @Faran2007 Ive added the answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable Windows console QuickEdit Mode from python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37500076/how-to-enable-windows-console-quickedit-mode-from-python)

Comment: @Shadesfear thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Shadesfear answer, take a look at this topic:
[How to enable Windows console QuickEdit Mode from python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37500076/how-to-enable-windows-console-quickedit-mode-from-python)
It's shown there how to enable it, and as Quick Edit Mode is [enabled by default in Windows 10](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/take-a-look-at-windows-10s-new-command-prompt-features/), you can use the code presented there to **disable** it as your program starts.

Comment: Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2):

To disable Quick edit mode do the following: right-click on the title bar and select Properties, then select Options, then you disable Quick Edit Mode, then the scrolling doesn't stop when you click in the window.

Comment: @Faran2007 As you said yourself it's not a problem with the code. 

If you just disable quick edit mode, it should work as intendet

Comment: yes it's not a problem code, but HOW do I disable quick-edit using python?

Comment: You question seems to be a duplicate of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37500076/how-to-enable-windows-console-quickedit-mode-from-python

Comment: Thanks for helping