# C# Console Application GetConsoleMode Errorcode 6

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a console game and i want to disable the mouse input. I've got the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656846/how-to-programmatic-disable-c-sharp-console-applications-quick-edit-mode) page, but when i try to run it the GetConsoleMode function fails with errorcode 6, which stands for "Invalid Handle".

So my question: Why does the GetConsoleWindow() method return an invalid console handle?

Here my sourcecode:

```
private static void DisableMouseInput()
{
    IntPtr consoleHandle = GetConsoleWindow();
    uint consoleMode;

    Console.WriteLine(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());         // get current console mode
    if (!GetConsoleMode(consoleHandle, out consoleMode))
    {
        // Error: Unable to get console mode.
        Console.WriteLine(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        throw new Exception();
        return;
    }
     // Clear the mouse input bit in the mode flags
    consoleMode = consoleMode & 0xffbf; //0xffef = ~0x0040 = ~ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT
    // set the new mode
    if (!SetConsoleMode(consoleHandle, consoleMode))
    {
        // ERROR: Unable to set console mode
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try another way to get `consoleHandle`?
For example:

```
const int STD_INPUT_HANDLE = -10;

[DllImport("kernel32.dll"]
static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);

private static foo() {
  IntPtr consoleHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
  ....
}
```