# Disable right-click paste function in console

Tags: c#

I have recently learned that pressing right-click on the console pastes whatever there is into the clipboard onto it. I have run into some issues with the console minigame I'm developing due to this, and I haven't been able to find how to disable this functionality, or even if it's possible.

Is there any way in C# to disable this console functionality?

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about the Windows command prompt. I just tested what you told me and it does what I wanted, but I would like to set it from the code so that when opening the application QuickEdit is disabled (so that not everyone that uses my code has to do that step beforehand). I don't know if that will be possible but I will research more now that I know the functionality name!

Comment: I've added an answer for you.  Good luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatic disable C# Console Application's Quick Edit mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656846/how-to-programmatic-disable-c-sharp-console-applications-quick-edit-mode)

Comment: My answer was in C++, sorry about that.  However I think somebody has the answer for you in the duplicate that I've flagged.