# Disable clipboard operations in console app

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, console-application

I have a console app which monitors assorted things 24/7 and will issue warnings if it detects any faults. The other day I noticed that it failed to warn me about something and I later worked out that I accidentally clicked on the app thereby highlighting a single text cell in the console and the app was then locked up waiting for me to perhaps "copy" the highlighted text. This is rather hard to spot and I am concerned that it could happen again. Is there a way to prevent such locking - perhaps disabling any clipboard operations altogether?

Comment: Maybe disable quick edit mode in the settings of the `CMD` window?

Comment: Like @Bodo said, right mouse button on the window header > properties > Options > Edit Options > Uncheck "Quick Edit Mode"

Comment: This article may be helpful. [How to programmatic disable C# Console Application's Quick Edit mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13656846/9014308)