# When something is highlighted in a debug console, execution just pauses until it's unhighlighted ... how do I stop this behaviour?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

- I start a visual studio project with debugging.
- The console pops up, and I often accidently highlight something, which causes execution to pause until I unhighlight it ... I don't want it to pause ever unless I've set appropriate breakpoints.

I've tried looking around at the various options, but nothing seemed appropriate.

Comment: This question is probably more suitable for Superuser as it is about Windows console behavior…

Comment: I'm not even sure how to even phrase the question, so it's a windows thing not a visual studio thing?

Comment: I found my answer @AlexeiLevenkov https://superuser.com/questions/1442941/windows-10-console-stops-running-if-i-click-in-the-console-window

Comment: In Windows, the console has 'QuickEditMode' enabled. 
You should turn this off. 
How to turn it off programmatically: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53391837/6725889

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This superuser response answers the question.

https://superuser.com/questions/1442941/windows-10-console-stops-running-if-i-click-in-the-console-window

Basically a change in behaviour since windows 10 where QuickEdit was enabled by default, so highlighting the console would cause the console to stop printing and pause the program. By disabling QuickEdit it will not longer pause.

Comment: Hi, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! You can click '✔' to accept your answer. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :) It will also help others to solve the similar issue.