# Topshelf in console when cancel key (CTRL+C) pressed force stop service

Tags: c#, .net, topshelf

I would like that Topshelf stops my service when I debug it in a console.

My code:

```
public class Program
{
    private static ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HostFactory.Run(Configure);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Configures the service host.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cfg">The HostConfigurator</param>
    private static void Configure(HostConfigurator cfg)
    {
        try
        {
            cfg.Service<ServiceHost>(s =>
            {
                s.ConstructUsing(name => new ServiceHost());
                s.WhenStarted(host => host.StartService());
                s.WhenStopped(host => host.StopService());
            });

            cfg.RunAsLocalSystem();
            cfg.StartManually();
            cfg.SetDisplayName(DisplayName);
            cfg.SetServiceName(ServiceName);
            cfg.UseLog4Net();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log.Fatal("Exception on Startup", ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

But when I press <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> it hangs in `Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.WaitForThreadExit`.

When I press <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> I would like that `host => host.StopService()` is called immediately.

Is that possible?

Comment: Have you tried turning off VS Hosting in your project's properties?

Comment: good idea!
i tried it but now it hangs in > mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne(System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle waitableSafeHandle, long millisecondsTimeout, bool hasThreadAffinity, bool exitContext) + 0x2b bytes 
:(

Comment: Ctrl+C is a pretty big hammer, pretty hard for code to dodge it.  You'll need to post a better stack trace to give us a guess.  Beware of a common deadlock in the Console class for .NET 4.5 RTM, do make sure you have Windows Update enabled to get the service release that fixes it.

Comment: The solution is to enabled unmanaged debugging and turn off the Control+C exception handler as discussed in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949106/vs2010-express-debugger-trapping-ctrlc-in-console-app

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible to intercept the CTRL+C by adding an event handler to the `Console.CancelKeyPress` event:

```
Console.CancelKeyPress += (s, e) => host.StopService();
```

Comment: i already tried this, it always blocks on "Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.WaitForThreadExit".

Comment: Seems that this is a bug in the .net framework: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/524889/debugging-c-console-application-that-handles-console-cancelkeypress-is-broken-in-net-4-0

Comment: @leozilla Yeah, but it seems to only be there when you're debugging. Perhaps you could use a different key combination to stop the service when debugging? For example, I'm waiting for "q" press, then I do a clean shutdown.

Comment: Topshelf's ConsoleRunHost already handles the Ctrl+C keypress.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely culprit is that your service's `StartService` method doesn't return control to Topshelf. What does your `StartService` do? It should only initialize any resources and start up your event loop/thread. Can you run `service install start` and get it to start up? If the service times out while starting up, it would also reinforce the idea that your start isn't returning.

Answer (score 0):

its a known bug with .NET 4.0, there is a workaround but its nasty

https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf/issues/10

Answer (score 0):

In VS2010, you need to:

1. Go to your project property, then navigate to Debug pane, check
   'Enable unmanaged code debugging'.
2. Toolbar Debug-> Exceptions ->
   then Uncheck the C++ Exceptions and the Win32 Exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

In your ServiceHost class implement IDisposeable, add a Dispose method, and dispose all your threaded objects.