# My consoleHandler does not handle CTRL+C even though properly set

Tags: c++, winapi, window

Related question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18291284/handle-ctrlc-on-win32)

but it does not work for me, when I press CTRL + C debugger issues "unhandled event", only closing the console works fine but not for CTRL + C, what is wrong with my code?

Here is the code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

BOOL WINAPI consoleHandler(DWORD signal) noexcept
{
    switch (signal)
    {
    case CTRL_C_EVENT:
        ExitProcess(0); // not working
    case CTRL_BREAK_EVENT:
        break;
    case CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT:
        ExitProcess(0); // this works
    case CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT:
    case CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT:
        break;
    }       

    return TRUE;
}

int main()
{
    if (!SetConsoleCtrlHandler(consoleHandler, TRUE))
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR: Could not set control handler" << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    DoSomeWork();

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolectrlhandler):

> CTRL+BREAK is always treated as a signal, but typical CTRL+C behavior
>   can be changed in three ways that prevent the handler functions from
>   being called:
>
> - The SetConsoleMode function can disable the ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT mode for a console's input buffer, so CTRL+C is reported as keyboard
>     input rather than as a signal.
> - Calling SetConsoleCtrlHandler with the NULL and TRUE arguments causes the calling process to ignore CTRL+C signals. This attribute is
>     inherited by child processes, but it can be enabled or disabled by any
>     process without affecting existing processes.
> - If a console process is being debugged and CTRL+C signals have not been disabled, the system generates a DBG_CONTROL_C exception. This
>     exception is raised only for the benefit of the debugger, and an
>     application should never use an exception handler to deal with it. If
>     the debugger handles the exception, an application will not notice the
>     CTRL+C, with one exception: alertable waits will terminate. If the
>     debugger passes the exception on unhandled, CTRL+C is passed to the
>     console process and treated as a signal, as previously discussed.

Perhaps the third point applies to your problem? Does your application behaves as expected when running in Release mode?

Comment: I have the same problem in release build, I have no idea what settings I need to adjust or what I need to do?

Comment: CTRL + C works on command line regardless if handler is set up. I need the functionality while debugging only.

Comment: Thank you, your solution led me to *google:* **CTRL+C + debugging + Visual Studio** and found the solution! 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949106/vs2010-express-debugger-trapping-ctrlc-in-console-app